# Singleton syntax in PHP code

Tags: php, syntax, singleton

I understand the singleton pattern, but I don't understand the following syntax:

```
    public static function get()
    {
      static $db = null;
      if ( $db == null )
        $db = new DatabaseConnection();
      return $db;
    }
    private function __construct()
    {
      $dsn = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/photos';
      $this->_handle =& DB::Connect( $dsn, array() );
    }
```

Why every time we call DatabaseConnection::get() we could ge the same singleton object? Because the code read from me will like:

```
    static $db = null; //set $db object to be null
    if($db==null)  // $db is null at the moment every time because we just set it to be null
      // call the private constructor every time we call get() *
      $db = new DatabaseConnection();  
    return $db;  // return the created
```

Then how the get() function could always return a same object?

I am new to Php, most of the syntax to me will read like java, please any one could explain this to me?

Also is there any instructions/tutorial that I could read for understanding more syntax sugar like:

```
       $array_object[] = $added_item
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are correct, and this wouldn't follow the Singleton pattern - quite confusing... I'd like to see if anyone disagrees.
As for `$array_object[] = $added_item`, it just adds `$added_item` to the next available index of the `$array_object` array ;) Though if you're interested in where you can find out similar stuff, I usually just check http://php.net/manual/en/

Comment: Also, if you put `static $db = null;` outside of the `get()` method, I think that would work just fine as it's only set to null the once. Maybe that's what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your class:

```
private static $db;

public static function get(){
    if(!self::$db){

         self::$db = new DatabaseConnection();

     }

    return self::$db;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this should work for singleton, just wonder the case that show on the example.